# formal function arguments followed by **kwargs in Function Calls

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I understand the function arguments must have the following **ordering hierarchy**:

1. Formal positional arguments
2. `*args`
3. Keyword arguments
4. `**kwargs`

I'm getting this error:

> SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

in the below:

```
def dfDiff(old, new, **kwargs):
    # default dict of optional function arguments
    d = {'city': 'Austin',
         'capital': True,
         'indx' : 5}
    # if optional args are provided 
    if kwargs is not None:
        # find the common keys
        k_passed = kwargs.keys() & d.keys()
        # change the default value
        for k in k_passed:
            d[k] = kwargs[k]    


test_ = dfDiff(1, 2, 'city' = 'Albany')
```

did I pass `**kwargs` incorrectly or there is some other issue?

Comment: ```city='Albany'```, don't wrap ```city``` in quotation marks.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi,  thanks, if you with make it an answer, i'll mark it accepted

Comment: `test_ = dfDiff(1, 2, 'city' = 'Albany')` attempts to asigns the value of the *expression* `'city' = 'Albany' to `**kwargs`. As you found out, Python doesn't allow expressions as keyword arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`city='Albany'`, don't wrap `city` in quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

As @MichaelBianconi said in comments, while giving keyword-arguments, you need not enclosing them as strings. Just treat them like variables.
So correct code is:

```
test_ = dfDiff(1, 2, city = 'Albany')
```

As per guidelines, don't have space between keyword, equal to and value.

```
test_ = dfDiff(1, 2, city='Albany')
```